# select details of max(billdate) in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to get billmonth of maximum billdate in a financial year of each institutions in an office

```
SELECT i.institution_code, 
       bill_month 
FROM   pfmast_institution i 
       LEFT JOIN pf_bills b 
              ON i.institution_code = b.institution_code 
                 AND fin_year = '2008-09' 
                 AND aproved = 'Y' 
WHERE  institution_dd_officecode = '1005' 
GROUP  BY i.institution_code, 
          bill_month 
ORDER  BY Max(bill_date), 
          i.institution_code DESC
```

Here the query is showing bill month of maximum billdate in each month.But I want billmonth of maximum billdate in each institution in a financial year.

Comment: can u please share the table structure

Comment: If bill_month is actually the month of the bill_date, won't SELECT i.institution_code, 
       max(bill_month) 
FROM   pfmast_institution i 
       LEFT JOIN pf_bills b 
              ON i.institution_code = b.institution_code 
                 AND fin_year = '2008-09' 
                 AND aproved = 'Y' 
WHERE  institution_dd_officecode = '1005' 
GROUP  BY i.institution_code
ORDER  BY  i.institution_code DESC  work?